# Jquery and Jquery UI don't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having quite an annoying problem.
While I have the correct files in my directory, and the syntax is correct, the .js file do not seem to load in and I can not use the functions that they include.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

These are my imports from my js folder. I am trying to do the following:

```
$("#dateinput").datepicker({});
```

since datepicker is a function in my jquery-ui-... it should work right? 
Anyways, my css loads, so I'd figured, let's load up my js files in my css folder and change the directory, but still nope.. When I control+click it does go to my correct file in the correct directory. So what am I forgetting?

Comment: So when one version didn't load, you decided to add a few more ?

Comment: You're loading both jquery and jquery-ui twice. Don't do that.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery UI css, and why do you have jQ 1.9.1 and ?

Comment: @adeneo we'll I've just been trying for some time now, therefor I might just have to clean up some lines, you're correct on that

Comment: @j08691 i'm loading it locally from netbeans into chrome

Comment: Well that's probably your problem then. Locally running it won't work with URLs like `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`. Add the `http:` in front and try again.

Comment: But the weird part is, that these links do work. i've cleaned up the double parts. It's the local files that won't load

Comment: @j08691 added the http: but still nothing

Comment: Are you using a webserver, like WAMP etc.

Comment: @DavidVandenbroucke are you getting an error `$ is undefined` in console..? if not, check whether your script is inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` or not, if not `#dateinput` might not have been created while the script runs...

Comment: If you run the page on a server, instead of via netbeans, does it work? Does the browser console show anything at any time?

Comment: nope, doesn't work, I'll have to redo some work, I broke everything now :p thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding the following code i got it working, but it seems less elegant..

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();



    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });



    $( "#button" ).button();
    $( "#radioset" ).buttonset();



    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();



    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Ok",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    // Link to open the dialog
    $( "#dialog-link" ).click(function( event ) {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        event.preventDefault();
    });



    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        inline: true
    });



    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        range: true,
        values: [ 17, 67 ]
    });



    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: 20
    });


    // Hover states on the static widgets
    $( "#dialog-link, #icons li" ).hover(
        function() {
            $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
        },
        function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
        }
    );
});
</script>
```